# VIM Compilation in windows

Tags: vim, compilation

I am interested in compiling windows for Python25 support but when I

```
make -f Make_ming.mak gvim.exe
```

I get the following (`_MAX_PATH undeclared`):

```
gcc -c -Iproto -DWIN32 -DWINVER=0x0400 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400 -DHAVE_PATHDEF -DFEAT_BIG -DHAVE_GETTEXT -DHAVE_LOCALE_H -DDYNAMIC_GETTEXT -DFEAT_CSCOPE -DFEAT_NETBEANS_INTG -DFEAT_GUI_W32 -DFEAT_CLIPBOARD -DFEAT_MBYTE -DFEAT_MBYTE_IME -DDYNAMIC_IME -DDYNAMIC_ICONV -pipe -w -march=i386 -Wall -DFEAT_PYTHON -I c:/Python25/include -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON -DYNAMIC_PYTHON_DLL=\"python25.dll\" -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -freg-struct-return -s fileio.c -o gobj/fileio.o
fileio.c: In function `buf_modname':
fileio.c:5877: error:_MAX_PATH' undeclared (first use in this function)
fileio.c:5877: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once 
fileio.c:5877: error: for each function it appears in.) 
fileio.c: In function `vim_tempname':
fileio.c:6832: error: `_MAX_PATH' undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [gobj/fileio.o] Error 1
```

Any ideas? What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't how to fix your problem myself, but I followed this video tutorial to do exactly what you are trying and it worked like a charm:

http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=1850010&fromSeriesID=185.

Comment: A link to a video is not really an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Vim text editor, why are you not using the [download](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc) version(s) from vim.org, etc. (gvim, [Cream](http://cream.sourceforge.net/download.html), [Portable Gvim](http://portablegvim.sourceforge.net/))

If you are trying to build Python for windows, why are you not using the current 2.6.1 or 3.0.1 from [python.org](http://www.python.org/)?

`_MAX_PATH` should maybe be `PATH_MAX` or `_PATH_MAX` which is defined via `stdlib.h` / `limits.h` or `sys/param.h` under Linux.

Have you checked any configuration logs? Any previous compiler warnings about missing includes or undefined values? Search for `PATH_MAX` and `PATH_MAX`.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest Portable GVim. It has not been updated for quite some time, and it seems author is no longer interested in the project. On the other hand, normal Gvim is perfectly portable with a few options in vimrc (so it doesn't leave any traces on the system).

Answer (score 0):

Is it just for the support of Python 2.5?

Not the answer to your question, but the easy way:
*downloaded the precompiled* vim.exe and gvim.exe from [gooli.org](http://www.gooli.org/blog/gvim-72-with-python-2526-support-windows-binaries/) (for Python 2.5 and/or 2.6)

Comment: Thanks I guess I will try. But I wanted to compile it myself.